# Banach space exercise

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T_{n} \in B(X,Y)$. If $T_{n}x_{n} \to 0$ in $Y$ for any
choice of unit vectors $\{x_{n}\}$ in $X$, show that $\|T_{n}\| \to 0$.

Comment: Could you include what you tried and where you got stuck?  If you don't know where to start, do you understand all the definitions involved?

What is "any choice of unit vectors $\{x_{n}\}$?  Is this a sequence of vectors of norm $1$?

Answer (score 2):

You want to chose $x_n$ such that $$\frac{||T_n||}2\leq |T_n x_n|$$ which you can always do by definition of the norm.

As $|T_n x_n| \longrightarrow 0$ thus so does $||T_n||$.